# How to create "group" column by values in column

Tags: r

```
 df <- data.frame(a = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5"),b = c(1:8))
```

I am trying to create a group column `df$c` so that variables "1", "2" and "3", and variables "4" and "5" in `df$a` are grouped together.

i.e.

```
  a b         c
"1" 1 "group a"
"1" 2 "group a"
"2" 3 "group a"
"3" 4 "group a"
"3" 5 "group a"
"4" 6 "group b"
"4" 7 "group b"
"5" 8 "group b"
```

I am unable to use `cut()` as this seems to require 2<  groups.

I attempted to convert column a to numeric class and use `ifelse()`.

```
df$a <- df$a %>% as.character %>% as.numeric
ifelse(df$a < 4, df$c == "group a", df$c == "group b"
```

But this coerced every variable to `NA`.

Comment: Both answers solve what I have been banging my head against a wall over for the last 2 hours. I picked yours because Pierre Lafortune's solution with cut needed two extra specifications to work for me. I am grateful for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I would also use PierreLafortune's suggestion if it was mentioned about more groups.  Also, I thought to show how to fix your `ifelse `code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need only a single logical statement i.e. for the `test`, the 'yes' and 'no' values are 'group a', and 'group b' respectively.

```
df$c <- ifelse(as.numeric(df$a) < 4, 'group a', 'group b')
```

But, this can be done without any `ifelse` too

```
df$c <-  c('group b', 'group a')[(as.numeric(df$a) < 4)+1L]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `cut` you can specify the outer edges of the breaks. This is advantageous to `ifelse` statements because it is much more scalable. If you had more groups with many cut points you wouldn't have to write out all of the conditionals:

```
df$c <- cut(as.numeric(df$a), c(1,3,5), c("group a", "group b"), include.lowest=TRUE)
#   a b       c
# 1 1 1 group a
# 2 1 2 group a
# 3 2 3 group a
# 4 3 4 group a
# 5 3 5 group a
# 6 4 6 group b
# 7 4 7 group b
# 8 5 8 group b
```

Comment: But, here the OP mentioned only about 2 groups.

Comment: @akrun yes, and in case they were making it simple for the example. Or if they or someone else researching this question has more groups.

Comment: That is just an assumption.  If the OP is showing only 2 groups and with an `ifelse` code, I wouldn't use `cut` considering that there are 100 groups.

Comment: They also mentioned a failed attempt at `cut` in the question. Just wanted to show how it could work for them too.

Comment: @akrun your answer was good. The vector subset shortcut solves it too.

Comment: thank you very much. For others that may find this answer I ran into problems through no fault of PLs answer. Instead of c(0,3,5) I used c(1,3,5) and therefore needed to specify include.lowest = TRUE and right = FALSE for this to work.

cut(as.numeric(df$a), c(0,3,5)